# Designer workflow kicking off multiple times and sending multiple emails

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow, email

I have created a designer workflow in SharePoint 2010 environment and users started using it it has multiple stages of approvals. Everything worked fine for 6 months of period.Users are having an issue in the final staging receiving emails as they were not getting mails.

- I applied wait condition in workflow and tested and workflow worked fine.
- Here is the issue as the users already have some of the items under In-progress as I published the workflow again with adding pause condition this made the In-Progress items to send multiple emails in the final stage.
- I am just wondering if this is due to designer workflow behavior or is there something gone wrong with my implementation.

Can someone would explain and let me know any resolution for this if any.

Comment: Is your workflow started manually, or on create/change?  Is it possible that both the old and new workflow are running on the items that are sending multiple emails?

Comment: HI Erin I have the options to start when an item is changed , created as well manually. Yes it is running on both old and new one's there the issue is raised.

Comment: So it sounds like the multiple instances of the workflow running on one item would be the cause of the multiple emails going out, yes?

Comment: Yes Erin. I am quite surprised as I have not changed any logic just maintained as is but a condition to pause has been added.But am confused on how it would work fine without duplicating the emails as users are being hitting their mail box with multiple emails.

Comment: Every time you publish a workflow, a different version of the workflow is created. Let's say you have a workflow called ApprovalStages. You publish it and it runs on an item. You publish it again, and that instance starts on the same object when it's changed. You do this a third time, and now you're going to have 3 emails sent to your user because all 3 versions of the workflow are running.

Comment: But how would i overcome this , is this the way designer workflow works and if I try with custom workflow this won't be any issue I suppose, because it created a heck of issue as users are going crazy on multiple mails.

Comment: There a few things you need to do. It sounds like the workflow is supposed to progress through stages just once. So the workflow should be set to run manually or on create, but not every single time the item is changed. Secondly, once you start a workflow on an item that version of the workflow will continue to run on that item and cannot be superseded by a publishing a new version of the workflow. You have to either let the original workflow run its course, or manually terminate it and start the other - which will start over from the beginning. Let me see if I can start a chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33386/discussion-between-erin-l-and-user2314241).